# Problem calling shell script from PHP which calls Java

Tags: java, php, shell

first I have to tell you, that i'm a french guy, so i can make some mistake with my english ;-)

Here is my problem : I want to use a java processor to transform a XML file. 
I made a shell script wich is working well.
But when I execute the shell script from PHP it doesn't work ...

```
// I tried this
$resultat = shell_exec("sh ".$chemin."script.sh");
// And after this
$resultat = shell_exec("java -jar ". $jar ." -s:".$source." -xsl:".$xslt);
```

The file "script.sh" contains this :

```
JAR='lib/saxon/saxon9he.jar'
SOURCE='temp/fichier_xml.xml'
RESULT="temp/output.xml"
XSLT="xml_to_xml.xsl"

java -jar $JAR -s:$SOURCE -xsl:$XSLT
```

I think that's a problem with JAVA ... But I can not resolve this !!

If you have an idea to help me,

Thanks

Comment: You should describe your variables.

Comment: Perhaps PHP's env doesn't have PATH set well? Or JAVA_HOME env var? Try full path like /usr/bin/java. Also, what is the error message? Turn on PHP error logs.

Comment: what's the error do your program prints ?

Comment: And please be more precise in the title - like "Problem calling shell script from PHP which calls Java."

Comment: @cularis the JAR have to transform a XML with a XSLT stylesheet, what doesn't work is the result of the transformation

->renenglish i don't have any error, that's one of the problem :-)

Variables : 
 - $JAR -> the location of the JAR file 
 - $SOURCE -> the XML source
 - $XSLT -> the xslt source

Answer (score 0):

Try using the script in backticks i.e. ``

Answer (score 0):

```
shell_exec('cd ' . $chemin . ' & sh script.sh');
```

1. Go to your $chemin dir
2. Then run your script, as java need correct pathes

Comment: Then try to add some debug echo's -- both in your sh script and in java. And you will understand where you have a problem.